ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to *
I'm developing hybrid Android application. When I use API 31, I am able to launch the application properly and perform all the functionality.
However, when I use API 33, I have a clipboard access error. Because of this, the application is getting force closed.
Error message in logcat:
2024-06-06 16:19:48.514  1726-8018  
WindowManager system_server V  Changing focus from Window{4e97908 u0 *bundle id* } to null displayId=0 Callers=**com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.updateFocusedWindowLocked**:568 **com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.updateFocusedWindowLocked**:6751 **com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.setLastResumedActivityUncheckLocked**:6060 **com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskSupervisor.updateTopResumedActivityIfNeeded**:2806 

2024-06-06 16:19:48.514  1726-6072  
InputDispatcher  system_server D  Focus entered window (0): 4e97908 *bundle id*

2024-06-06 16:19:48.517  1726-8018  
ClipboardService system_server E  Denying clipboard access to *bundle id*, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0

2024-06-06 16:19:48.518  1726-2088  
ImeTracker system_server I  *bundle id* :22e548c7: onRequestHide at ORIGIN_SERVER_HIDE_INPUT reason HIDE_SAME_WINDOW_FOCUSED_WITHOUT_EDITOR

2024-06-06 16:19:48.518  1726-2088  
ImeTracker system_server I *bundle id* :22e548c7: onCancelled at PHASE_SERVER_SHOULD_HIDE

